# PhpStorm adding unwanted tab after ?>

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm is adding an unwanted tab character below my first closing `?>` tag. As you can see in the screenshot, the paragraph has a tab in front of it. I've searched through the code styles and can't seem to find where to change this.

This is bizarre because it does not happen if I have HTML above the first `<?php` tag.

Where do I turn this off so it doesn't get tabbed when I reformat the code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in IDE.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34740 -- try adding your code sample/comment there.

---

Possible solution (not sure how acceptable that is, possibly not really):

- add closing `?>` tag
- ensure that there is a blank empty line at the very end

Comment: To help with the second workaround, there is "Ensure line feed at file end on Save" option in Settings->Editor->General.